# Изменить количество процессов php-cgi

Tags: php, lighttpd, debian

На  debian 7.0 стоит lighttpd + php-cgi.

Пишу после всяких манипуляций с конфигом

```
reboot // ждем, пока перезагрузится, подключаемся к ssh заново
ps -A | grep php
```

Вот вывод консоли :

```
 3632 ?        00:00:00 php-cgi
 3637 ?        00:00:00 php-cgi
 3649 ?        00:00:00 php-cgi
 3651 ?        00:00:00 php-cgi
```

Можно ли как-то ограничить кол-во php-cgi-процессов (воркеров)?

Мне http-сервер вообще нужен только как web-морда к приложению, и подключаться я буду один, а тут 4 процесса.

Comment: почитайте [документациию](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Lighttpd_(%D0%A0%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9), ищите по слову "max-procs"). Это же просто. Но я бы не трогал.

Comment: @eicto, спасибо

Comment: @KoVadim, с англ. не очень пока что.

Comment: Там вообще-то даже по русский, только ссылка кривая получилась, в неё попала подсказка «ищите по слову». Вот ссылка: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Lighttpd_%28%D0%A0%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9%29

Ключевое слово для поиска max-procs.

P.S. а читать маны в оригинале советую научиться, это не трудно (язык там далеко не шекспировский, да и пишут их зачастую не нативные англо-говорящие люди). На русском языке инфы конечно не мало, но всё-же гораздо меньше (и среднее качество её ниже, ибо пересказы) чем на английском.

Comment: @KoVadim, в интересах истории оформите ответ как ответ.

Comment: @MrClon, спасибо за хорошую ссылку. пробовал max-procs

Comment: Тогда давай конфиги. А вообще лучше просто не заморачиваться и оставить как есть, если нет острой необходимости сэкономить пару килобайт памяти. Не сломано — не чини

Comment: Да, насчет "не сломано - не чини" - правильно. Уже 3 раза переустанавливал VPS, пытаясь все переделать

Вот конф: 

http://paste.org.ru/?osfspy

Comment: >Уже 3 раза переустанавливал VPS, пытаясь все переделать

Так чего ради? Чем больше ты переделаешь тем больше у тебя будет шансов где-то накосячить, тем труднее тебе потом будет разобраться в переделанном. Любое изменение следует производить только если ты понимаешь зачем ты это делаешь.

Answer (score 1):

лучше не изменять это значение.

но если очень нужно, то в [конфигурации](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Lighttpd_%28%D0%A0%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9%29#PHP) `fastcgi.server` следует изменить параметр `max-procs`:

```
fastcgi.server = (
   ".php" => (( 
      "bin-path" => "/usr/bin/php-cgi",
      "socket" => "/var/run/lighttpd/php-fastcgi" + PID + ".sock",
      "max-procs" => 4, # значение по умолчанию
      "bin-environment" => (
         "PHP_FCGI_CHILDREN" => "1", # значение по умолчанию
         "PHP_FCGI_MAX_REQUESTS" => "10000"
      ),
      "broken-scriptfilename" => "enable"
   ))
)
```